# PHP cURL consistently taking 15s to resolve DNS

Tags: php, curl

I'm running PHP on a CentOS virtual machine under MacOS X, and any cURL request consistently takes 15s to run:

```php
$c = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com');
curl_exec($c); // takes 15s to return...
echo curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME); // 15.01 seconds
```

However, [gethostbyname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php) is very fast:

```php
echo gethostbyname('graph.facebook.com'); // almost instant
```

And, `ping` resolves the name almost instantly as well.

By default, `/etc/resolv.conf` only had `nameserver 192.168.1.1` in it, so I changed it to use the Google DNS servers:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

But with no luck. Any hints?

---

**Update 1**: The following fixes the problem:

```php
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
```

So as far as I understand it, it's trying to resolve both IPv4 and IPv6, and IPv6 resolution fails, after a timeout of 15s.

It that because of a misconfiguration on the Linux machine?

---

**Update 2**:

```
dig graph.facebook.com aaaa

;; reply from unexpected source: 10.0.2.2#53, expected 192.168.1.1#53
;; reply from unexpected source: 10.0.2.2#60944, expected 192.168.1.1#53
;; reply from unexpected source: 10.0.2.2#53, expected 192.168.1.1#53

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.4 <<>> graph.facebook.com aaaa
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: How long does it take if you do `curl_init('https://66.220.152.19');`

Comment: Can you do a packet capture and confirm that cURL is reporting this correctly?

Comment: @Alex I've tried it with the IP address, and it's very quick. Definitely a DNS problem, as highlighted by `CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME`.

Comment: you can check your config by going to test-ipv6.com

Comment: Not sure why that's causing the problem, I have no problem looking up the IPv6 address of graph.facebook.com here. Do you have a problem with `dig graph.facebook.com aaaa`?

Comment: @Barmar Please see the result for `dig` in my updated question!

Comment: There's something very weird going on in your environment. Do you recognize that 10.0.2.2 address, is it another address of 192.168.1.1? Do you get the same response if you do `dig graph.facebook.com aaaa @8.8.8.8`?

Comment: I suspect this is some kind of firewall or proxy issue in your network.

Comment: @Barmar it works when adding `@8.8.8.8`! How come it's still using `192.168.1.1` even though I've removed it from `resolv.conf`?

Comment: If you haven't restarted the webserver, it may have the old resolv.conf parameters cached.

Comment: To answer your questions: no I don't recognize 10.0.2.2, but it's still pinging when I unplug the network cable, so it must be internal to the virtual machine, or the host (MacOS). Also, I've tried to stop both `iptables` on the guest and the firewall on the host (which was off already), no more luck.

Comment: @Barmar Ok, I see where the problem is now: after every reboot, the `resolv.conf` file is reset automatically to `192.168.1.1`, and has the following header: `; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script`. Do you know how to disable that?

Comment: Sorry, not very familiar with using DHCP on Linux, but I suspect there's a .conf or .rc file that specifies what parameters should be configured.

Comment: Ok, found the solution [here](http://grokbase.com/t/centos/centos/09a86yhgha/resolv-conf-rewritten-every-reboot-how-to-figure-out-who-and-why): adding `PEERDNS=no` to `ifcfg-eth0` solves the problem! Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem was an IPv6 lookup failing on my machine. The solution:

Changed `/etc/resolv.conf` to:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

After rebooting, `resolv.conf` got overwritten, so adding this line to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` (which was using `BOOTPROTO=dhcp`) fixed the problem:

```
PEERDNS=no
```

And everything now works like a charm.

As an alternative, if you experience this problem on a server on which you can not change the configuration, configure cURL this way:

```php
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
```

Comment: I went to follow your idea of modifying file `/etc/resolv.conf`
and it shows the message
`# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.`
Are you sure it is all right to edit file that should not be edited?

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev Looks like it's *not* safe when using DHCP, but in my case, setting `PEERDNS=no` stopped the file from being overwritten. Google "*resolv.conf overwritten*" and see if there are better solutions!

Comment: This was a very helpful answer, and the `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);` call worked perfectly in a situation where reconfiguring the server was not possible! Page loading is now much faster as the server-side retrieval via cURL is no longer being delayed by the IPv6 DNS resolution. Great suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With `PHP 7.1.32` installed with `brew` on macos, I got exactly this problem. `file_get_contents` and `curl` do not use the same DNS.

Like @schumyxp said, you can resolve manually first:

```
<?php
$ip = gethostbyname("XXXXX.infra");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://" . $ip);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: XXXXX.infra'));
```

BTW it's may be a good to force an IP instead of rely on a resolver.

Answer (score -1):

There may be something wrong in your system, but I find a way to work around it.

```
$urldata = parse_url($yourUrl);  
$host = $urldata['host'];  
$ip = gethostbyname($host);  
$new_Url_dns_resolved = str_replace($host,$ip,$yourUrl);  
//call the dns resolved url instead of the original url  
$c = curl_init($new_Url_dns_resolved);
```

Comment: Erm... 1/ The DNS problem was machine-wise, so using `gethostbyname()` won't help; 2/ replacing the host with the IP is most likely doomed to failure, as most websites today use name-based virtual hosts; 3/ I have already found the reason to my problem, explained it above, and posted the solution; not sure what's your motive..? No offence, but ... ;-)

Comment: @Benjamin Yes you are right. Although it works from my side, but it IS not a  correct way. 1/ the gethostbyname() works on my side because my DNS problem caused by the PHP's curl . 2/ as you say, most websites today use name-based virtual hosts so it will not work on most websites.