# Curl from php takes more time than curl via putty

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to send a curl request to googleapis, to fetch a users information. When I use a php script to send the cURL request, it takes 5 seconds to complete, yet, when I try to send the same request directly from the server with a curl command, the result return instantly.

Here's the php script I use:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Authorization: Bearer '.$accessToken));
$output=curl_exec($ch);
```

And here is the curl command I've used with putty:

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx" https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
```

What could be the problem?

**NOTE:** The php script runs on the same server from which I emmited the curl command via putty

**NOTE 2:** Could this be some kind of DNS lookup problem? At first, running this same command via command line also took around 5 seconds to complete, because www.googleapis.com was not in our DNS server. Since then, we added it manually, and the command line function runs much quicker. What kind of DNS information is PHP using, if I update the DNS info on the server, does it automatically gets updated for PHP too?

**NOTE 3:**
dig www.googleapis.com returns the following:

> ; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.4 <<>> www.googleapis.com
>   ;; global options: +cmd 
>   ;; Got answer: 
>   ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 5273 
>   ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
>
> ;; QUESTION SECTION: 
>   ;www.googleapis.com.            IN      A
>
> ;; ANSWER SECTION: 
>   www.googleapis.com.     1536    IN      CNAME   googleapis.l.google.com. 
>   googleapis.l.google.com. 172    IN      A       216.58.218.170
>
> ;; Query time: 0 msec 
>   ;; SERVER: 10.0.80.11#53(10.0.80.11) 
>   ;; WHEN: Wed Sep  9 14:35:04 2015 
>   ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 89

Comment: How are you executing the PHP code? I assume both succeed?

Comment: Both are succeeding, both return the exact same response, only the php version takes 5 seconds to complete, while the direct version only takes <1 seconds. The above php code is part of a larger script, but if I comment out the $output=curl_exec($ch); line, the whole script executes in less then a second:|

Comment: Are you running script from CLI? If so - are you sure it's problem with curl? I had similar 5second timeout. And it was not curl problem, but php startup delay. To check i its startup problem (in case of cli) simply try to run: php -r 'echo 1;'  And check how long it takes.

Comment: Running php -v from server results in an instant answer, while running it via exec() in a php script, it takes around 0.07 seconds, so I don't think this could be the problem. Also, please note, that if I take out the curl_exec line from my script, the whole script runs in less than a second

Comment: Same results with php -r 'echo 1;'...

Comment: Added a note to the original question

Comment: what is the output of `dig www.googleapis.com`? i.e. how long does the record live and how long does it take to get the record and from which sever?

Comment: I don't really understand how dig works, but this is what I get back from it, when run from command line (pasting it in the question, because the answer is long)

Comment: since there is a cname, the ttl of www.googleapis.com is probably 3600s, while the cname googleapis.l.google.com has a ttl of 300s? therefor if your dns server is slow, you will expierience the delay every time the record has to be fetched again (every 300s or less). you should see a decreasing number before IN. if this one hits zero the record would be fetched again next time. look at the query time if this number jumps from around 0 to ~300

Comment: Do the functions curl_getInfo() and curl_error() show anything ?

Comment: Please check following parameters "total_time", "namelookup_time", "connect_time", "pretransfer_time" and "speed_download" from your machine.

Comment: Didn't know about curl_getInfo() till now, but strangely it says, the following things: pretransfer_time is 5.029, namelookup_time is 5.003, starttransfer_time is 5.096 and total_time is 5.096. So basicaly this IS a DNS problem, while from the above data, I presume most of the time is spent with the namelookup. I've also tried executing the same curl command with an exec() in php, and if I do it that way, the whole script finishes in under 1 second. So the problem is with the DNS lookup of php's curl library, but I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Try following, print_r the returned array and tell me the above mentioned parameters:

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

Comment: Found the solution, but still don't really understand why it is doing this in another stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17816201/2691879. I am posting the answer from there, to this thread, but if someone cares to explain why is this happening in more detail, in a new answer, I will accept that as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer to the problem here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17816201/2691879

Setting this option, solves the problem:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
```

I still don't really understand why and how is this working/happening, so if someone cares to explain it to me in another answer, together with the above solution, I will mark that as the correct answer.