# cURL is not working anymore giving a 408 error

Tags: php, curl

I have a cURL code which was working before but recently it stopped working and gives a 408 request timeout error. I want to know the reason why it stopped working and how can I fix it.
Here's the code :

```
$curlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, $actualUrl); 
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,1100);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $clientcert); 
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, 'PEM'); 
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE, 'PEM'); 
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $keyfile); 
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
$data = curl_exec($curlSession);
```

> I tried it with the Postman application and it still works on Postman without any delay.Is there any alternative to cURL that I can use to check this?

Comment: Maybe its related to DNS problems on your Server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17814925/php-curl-consistently-taking-15s-to-resolve-dns

Comment: I tried it on 2 different servers and it gives the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 408 Request Timeout error is an HTTP status code that means the request you sent to the website server (e.g. a request to load a web page) took longer than the website's server was prepared to wait. In other words, your connection with the website "timed out."

You can test your API with postman first to see whether it is working fine.

Is your api return large amount of data or your remote server is slow resulting a long request-response time?

See documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

`CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` - The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect. Use 0 to wait indefinitely.

`CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` - The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400); //timeout in seconds
```

also don't forget to enlarge time execution of php script if needed.

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: Yeah. I'm sorry I forgot to mention that. I tried it with Postman and it works. The data isn't so large and it used to work before. I just wanted to know why it stopped.

Comment: I tried it with 1000 timeout. Is there any alternative to cURL in php that I can check with.

Comment: can you test the api from server using terminal or any other tools.When your working stable software suddenly stop working, more often it is not an issue in your code rather than server side or network issue.Also for an alternative of CURL you can see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents).

Comment: That's what I want to know. What is the server or network issue that happened suddenly, so I can fix it.